# How to get Address Lookup Tables owned by given Pubkey via filtering the LookupTableProgramAccounts?

Tags: getprogramaccounts, lookup-tables

I want to retrieve the LookupTables of a certain Pubkey by filtering the LookupTableProgram accounts. Which filter do I need to set to filter for a given authority?

```
let accounts = rpc_client
    .get_program_accounts_with_config(
        &lookup_program_pk,
        RpcProgramAccountsConfig {
            filters: todo!(),
            account_config: RpcAccountInfoConfig {
                encoding: todo!(),
                data_slice: todo!(),
                commitment: todo!(),
                min_context_slot: todo!(),
            },
            with_context: todo!(),
        },
    )
    .await?;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the definition of the `State` enum at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/22d4c6abf29219afa7d5c8553bdb607c2bb59f3c/programs/address-lookup-table/src/state.rs#L20-L28 and the `LookupTableMeta` at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/22d4c6abf29219afa7d5c8553bdb607c2bb59f3c/programs/address-lookup-table/src/state.rs#L40-L57, we need to count up to the authority! We've got

- enum: 4 bytes
- deactivation_slot: 8 bytes
- last_extended_slot: 8 bytes
- last_extended_slot_start_index: 1 byte
- authority: 33 bytes (1 byte for optionality, 32 bytes for the pubkey)

So if you're checking for a particular authority, you'll need to search for the pubkey bytes with `1` beforehand at index `4 + 8 + 8 + 1` = `21`, so you'll want something like:

```
let mut bytes = vec![1];
bytes.extend_from_slice(pubkey.as_ref());
RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp::new_raw_bytes(21, bytes)),
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks so much!